# What causes the black shimmering bands on a sun-lit surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, sun, ideal-gas

I can't figure it out. I thought it was the window causing it, but even without it it happened. It seems to be the motion of the air that causes it, but **why shimmering black bands?** Sometimes this happens when the surface is *not* hot at all.

Comment: can you post an image, please?

Comment: @Helder Velez I'm pretty sure these bands cannot be seen by my camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sun heats up the surface that it's light touches and the heat created causes the air to rise and the light hitting the hot air causes a mirage. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage

Comment: Could be, but why black shimmering bands?

Comment: @HyperLuminal as my Physics prof said, "because the sky is shiny."  There's a lot of light coming downwards and the delta index of refraction at the air layers causes a near-specular reflection. By comparison, dirt, vegetation, roads, etc. scatter light and are seen by us as "not shiny."